# JSON - Display data according to the index of json

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, indexing

I'm trying to display particular json data in a form of **Bullets**. Each ***chapter*** data into `<li>`, each ***title*** into `<p>` and make those titles as a `link`. Finally, consider to the index of clicked ***title*** display related ***content***  in a second `<div>`. I have already some piece of code below (not working yet).

**Html**:

```
<div id="page1">
    <ul id="courses"></ul>
</div>
<div id="page2">
    <p id="content"></p>
</div>
```

**JS code**:

```
var jsonString = '[{"chapter":"General","title":"News forum","content":"Text1"},
{"chapter":"CHAPTER 1","title":"1.1 Introduction","content":"Text2"},
{"chapter":"CHAPTER 1","title":"1.2 Main Idea","content":"Text3"},
{"chapter":"CHAPTER 2","title":"2.1 Architecture","content":"Text4"},
{"chapter":"CHAPTER 3","title":"3.1 Liter.overview","content":"Text5"}]';

var myData = JSON.parse(jsonString);

$(document).ready(function() {
    var $clist = $('#courses');
    for(var i in myData) {
        $('<li><h3>' +this.[i].chapter+ '</h3><p><a href="#page2" onclick="dContent(i)">' +this.title+ '</a></p></li>').appendTo($clist);
    }

    function dContent() {
        var $ccontent = $('#content');
        $(this.[i].content).appendTo($ccontent);
    }
});
```

Expected result:

```
- General
    News forum          // onclick display 'Text1' in <p id="content">
- CHAPTER 1
    1.1 Introduction    // onclick display 'Text2' in <p id="content">
    1.2 Main Idea       // onclick display 'Text3' in <p id="content">
- CHAPTER 2
    2.1 Architecture    // onclick display 'Text4' in <p id="content">
- CHAPTER 3
    3.1 Liter.overview  // onclick display 'Text5' in <p id="content">
```

Any help would be appreciated.

**UPDATE**: Here is the [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/rutZA/) project.

Comment: You will need to capture `i` in it's own scope in the loop, use a generator function or store the data somewhere else (e.g. _data-*_ attribute) to create your desired onclick listeners.

Comment: What exactly is not working?

Comment: @FelixKling nothing is printing for the result. Please have a look to the **jsfiddle** (link is above) version.

Comment: @PaulS. could you explain with an example please. thanks in advance

Comment: You need to select jQuery form the library dropdown in your jsfiddle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var jsonString = '[{"chapter":"General","title":"News forum","content":"Text1"},{"chapter":"CHAPTER 1","title":"1.1 Introduction","content":"Text2"},{"chapter":"CHAPTER 1","title":"1.2 Main Idea","content":"Text3"},{"chapter":"CHAPTER 2","title":"2.1 Architecture","content":"Text4"},{"chapter":"CHAPTER 3","title":"3.1 Liter.overview","content":"Text5"}]';
var myData = JSON.parse(jsonString);

var dContent = function(event) {
    $ccontent.html($(this).data('content'));
}

var $clist = $('#courses');
var $ccontent = $("#content");
var html = '';
var chapterList = [];

$clist.on('click', 'li', dContent);

$.each(myData, function(index, item) {
    if ($.inArray(item.chapter, chapterList) === -1) {
        chapterList.push(item.chapter);
        html += '<li data-content="'+ item.content +'"><h3>' + item.chapter + '</h3><p><a href="#page2">' + item.title + '</a></p></li>';
    }
    else {
        html += '<li data-content="'+ item.content +'"><p><a href="#page2">' + item.title + '</a></p></li>'
    }
});
$clist.html(html);
```

Comment: have checked your code, but the result is empty. you could check the `jsfiddle` project, that I have created (link is above)

Comment: ah sorry i forgot to enable JQuery, now it's working, thank a lot. By the way is it possible to avoid repeate of CHAPTER 1 and merge these two titles (title 1.1 and 1.2)? thanks in advance

Comment: I just added a little chapter list array that checks if the chapter has already been added before adding it again. If this works for you, can you throw the solution my way? Trying to bring my reputation up ;) http://jsfiddle.net/andyzinsser/5p3xu/2/. Good Luck!

Comment: now the `chapters` dislpaying without _duplication_, that is good. but I there are no duplicate `titles` and I need (in above case) to include both (or more if there is exists) titles into associated chapters. See the expected result above in the question:`1.1 Introduction and 1.2 Main Idea` topics included into **one** CHAPTER 1

Comment: Updated the example and the fiddle for you http://jsfiddle.net/andyzinsser/5p3xu/4/

Answer (score 1):

You have an invalid JSON structure. The correct structure is below:

```
[
    {
        "chapter": "General",
        "title": "News forum",
        "content": "Text1"
    },
    {
        "chapter": "CHAPTER 1",
        "title": "1.1 Introduction",
        "content": "Text2"
    },
    {
        "chapter": "CHAPTER 1",
        "title": "1.2 Main Idea",
        "content": "Text3"
    },
    {
        "chapter": "CHAPTER 2",
        "title": "2.1 Architecture",
        "content": "Text4"
    },
    {
        "chapter": "CHAPTER 3",
        "title": "3.1 Liter.overview",
        "content": "Text5"
    }
]
```

Note that comma here `3.1 Liter.overview","content":"Text5"},` in your JSON structure, it fails here

**UPDATED ANSWER WITH CODE**

```
var jsonString = '[{"chapter": "General","title": "News forum","content": "Text1"},{"chapter": "CHAPTER 1","title": "1.1 Introduction","content": "Text2"},{"chapter": "CHAPTER 1","title": "1.2 Main Idea", "content": "Text3"},{"chapter": "CHAPTER 2","title": "2.1 Architecture","content": "Text4"},{"chapter": "CHAPTER 3","title": "3.1 Liter.overview","content": "Text5"}]';

var myData = JSON.parse(jsonString);
$(document).ready(function() {
    function dContent() {
       $("#content").css("border","2px solid red").css("height","100px");
       $("#content").html($(this).data('value'));
    }
     $("#courses").on('click','li', dContent) 
    $.each(myData, function(index,item) { 
    $("#courses").append("<li class='li' data-value="+item.content+">"+item.chapter+"  <p>"+item.title+"</p></li>");

    })



});
```

[**DEMO ON JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/refhat/Yfdcx/)

Comment: thanks for the hint, it's was only misprint... already corrected

Answer (score 1):

I've written a script to do this, including putting items from the same chapter together. You can see a [**demo fiddle here**](http://jsfiddle.net/qWT4L/).

I used native JavaScript for most of it, with the exception of jQuery for the `$(a).on('click', ..` and `$(document).ready` to ensure compatibility. Why is it so long? Because I built the `<ul>` with DOM methods, instead of a html string. This made it easy to cache and append elements. Finally, the content is added via a generator function. The way I did it means the page will use slightly more memory but you can have **any** string that is valid in JavaScript displayed in the content section. You may want to style it with `whitespace: pre-wrap;` to display new lines as expected.

Anyway, here is the code

```
var jsonString = '[{"chapter":"General","title":"News forum","content":"Text1"},\
{"chapter":"CHAPTER 1","title":"1.1 Introduction","content":"Text2"},\
{"chapter":"CHAPTER 1","title":"1.2 Main Idea","content":"Text3"},\
{"chapter":"CHAPTER 2","title":"2.1 Architecture","content":"Text4"},\
{"chapter":"CHAPTER 3","title":"3.1 Liter.overview","content":"Text5"}]';
// the \ at line ends is to escape the new line in the string literal

var myData = JSON.parse(jsonString);

$(document).ready(function() {
    var courses_ul = document.getElementById('courses'), // cache elements
        content_elm = document.getElementById('content'),
        i, li, h3, p, a, // vars for loop
        chapters = {}, chap; // cache chapters
    for (i = 0; i < myData.length; ++i) {
        chap = myData[i].chapter; // shorthand since we'll use it a few times
        // make <p>, <a>
        p = document.createElement('p');
        a = document.createElement('a'); // could append <a> to <p> here if you want
        a.setAttribute('href', '#page2');
        a.appendChild(document.createTextNode(myData[i].title));
        // set up click
        $(a).on('click', (function (content) { // generator - will give scope to
            return function () { // this returned event listener.
                content_elm.innerHTML = '';
                content_elm.appendChild(document.createTextNode(content));
            };
        }(myData[i].content))); // chose `content` not `i` so no reliance on `myData`
        // now check cache if chapter exists -
        if (chap in chapters) { // retreive <li> for chapter from cache
            li = chapters[chap]; // from cache
            // append <p>, <a>
            li.appendChild(p).appendChild(a);
        } else { // if not in cache
            li = document.createElement('li'); // make a new <li>
            chapters[chap] = li; // and cache
            // make & append <h3>
            h3 = document.createElement('h3');
            h3.appendChild(document.createTextNode(chap));
            li.appendChild(h3);
            // append <p>, <a> and to <ul>
            courses_ul.appendChild(li).appendChild(p).appendChild(a);
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`this.[i].chapter` should probably be `myData[i].chapter`.  As it is, it's a syntax error.

Then you should rethink whether your other uses of `this` are correct.

Answer (score 0):

Copying this into your JSFiddle and checking in jQuery as well, will make it work.

```
var jsonString = '[{"chapter":"General","title":"News forum","content":"Text1"},{"chapter":"CHAPTER 1","title":"1.1 Introduction","content":"Text2"},{"chapter":"CHAPTER 1","title":"1.2 Main Idea","content":"Text3"},{"chapter":"CHAPTER 2","title":"2.1 Architecture","content":"Text4"},{"chapter":"CHAPTER 3","title":"3.1 Liter.overview","content":"Text5"}]';

var myData = JSON.parse(jsonString);

$(document).ready(function() {
    var $clist = $('#courses');

    $.each(myData, function(i,o){
        $('<li><h3>' +o.chapter+ '</h3><p>' +
          '<a href="#page2" onclick="dContent(\''+o.content+'\')">' +
          o.title + '</a></p></li>').appendTo($clist);
    });

    window.dContent = function(content) {
        var $ccontent = $('#content');
        $ccontent.append(content);

    } 
});
```

Comment: only one question: how to avoid the repeated name of `chapters`, namely I want push `1.2 Main Idea` into `CHAPTER 1` since it's a part of this chapter. THanks in advance.

Comment: Few issues with this one. 1. Attaching a function as a global var to the window is a dangerous practice. 2. If you have a long list of chapters, you have to do a DOM look up for each chapter (less optimized pattern)